# W3C Validation - Attribute buttonindex not allowed on element a at this point

Tags: javascript, html, validation, w3c

I getting the error "Attribute buttonindex not allowed on element a at this point". My code is

```
<p><a class="btn btn-success_ar hidden-xs" id="indexCarouselBeforeBtn2" buttonindex="2" role="button">HOVER HERE TO SEE BEFORE</a></p>
```

and my Script is

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var imageList = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    var totalSlides = 5;
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalSlides; i++) {

        imageList[i] = [];

        imageList[i][0] = $('<img />').attr('src', 'after/images/external/index' + i + 'after.jpg').attr('id', 'indexCarouselImg' + i);
        imageList[i][1] = $('<img />').attr('src', 'after/images/external/index' + i + 'before.jpg').attr('id', 'indexCarouselImg' + i);


        $("#indexCarouselBeforeBtn" + i).mouseenter(function(){

            $("#indexCarouselImg" + $(this).attr('buttonindex')).remove();
            $("#item" + $(this).attr('buttonindex')).append(imageList[$(this).attr('buttonindex')][1]);
            $(this).addClass('btnHover');
        });

        $("#indexCarouselBeforeBtn" + i).mouseleave(function(){

            $("#indexCarouselImg" + $(this).attr('buttonindex')).remove();
            $("#item" + $(this).attr('buttonindex')).append(imageList[$(this).attr('buttonindex')][0]);
            $(this).removeClass('btnHover');
        });

        $("#indexCarouselImg" + i).remove();
        $("#item" + i).append(imageList[i][0]);
    }
});
```

The error still exists even using P and Div tags instead of the a tag . How can I fix this.

Comment: There is no such attribute in HTML5. If you need this to supply information to some scripting logic, then use a custom data attribute.

Comment: I updated my question with Java script

Comment: What for? Search&replace is something you should be capable of yourself, right?

Comment: There is a `<button>` element to be used for buttons. It's accessible by default and doesn't need special treatment like adding `role="button"` to behave like a button. There is no need to (ab)use `<a>`, `<div>` and other elements for that.

Comment: And to validate your code, replace your custom `buttonindex` attribute with `data-buttonindex` throughout your code. The `data-`prefixed attributes are always considered valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's attribute not exists in HTML.

You can use tabindex.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: replace all "buttonindex" with "tabindex" in your javascript

Comment: Tabindex attribute is for keyboard navigation. If buttons are indexed for other purpose, it's better to do it with different attribute, with `data-` prefix if formal "validity" is important.